# Wifi disappears after boot

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager

I was using Zorin OS 16 and my wifi started disconnecting (it did not happen for months after I install Zorin 16) after like 5 minutes later after boot and I was not able to see any wifi in `Networks` section after the disconnect. I couldn't find a solution so I switched to Kubuntu 22.04. Now I still have the same issue. Weird thing is, this does not happen at work internet, it happens only on my home internet.

I have another laptop with different wifi adapter and there are no issues with it.

### What I tried so far:

- Reset modem
- Install [this](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) (after installing this it was okay whole day but after then I went to job and came back and it occured again)
- re-install NetworkManager

Here is my wifi adapter:

```
  *-generic                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: ff
       serial: ac:50:de:3e:52:65
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:155 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84000000-8400ffff
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score 1):

I changed `wifi.powersave` from 3 to 2 in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and no problems so far. I'll update here if it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems that solved disabling (with a workaround) my network card power-saving... long story - short solution...

try to run the following script as cron job (root user), and let me know if this solve your issue.

PS: I think it's a driver issue, but in my case this workaround solve the problem. Let me updated, please.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=""

* * * * * root for i in {1..12}; do (echo 'on' > /sys/class/net/"$(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -v '^lo')"/power/control) 2>/dev/null; sleep 5; done;
```

PPS: The `"$(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -v '^lo')"` block is used to find the first Ethernet Device Card.

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: try replacing the last line cron job script with the following one: `* * * * * root for i in {1..12}; do (ping -c 1 example.com) 2>/dev/null; sleep 4; done;`